# How do I test if my model is valid in Rails and minitest?

Tags: unit-testing, model, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm using rails 5.0.1 and minitest.  I want to write a simple test to validate my model.  The model file is

```
class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stop, foreign_key: "stop_onestop_id"
  belongs_to :vehicle, required: false
  belongs_to :line, foreign_key: "line_onestop_id"
  validates :types, presence: true
end
```

and teh schema is

```
  create_table "issues", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "stop_onestop_id"
    t.integer  "vehicle_id"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "line_onestop_id"
    t.string   "types"
    t.boolean  "resolved"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["stop_onestop_id"], name: "index_issues_on_stop_onestop_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_issues_on_user_id"
    t.index ["vehicle_id"], name: "index_issues_on_vehicle_id"
  end
```

so I wrote my test at test/models/issue_test.rb as

```
require 'test_helper'

class IssueTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'valid issue' do
    issue = Issue.new(types: 'Cleanliness')
    assert user.valid?
  end

end
```

but when I run my test, it crashes in a most spectacular way.  I can't figure out what's wrong.  Here's the output

```
localhost:myproject davea$ rails test test/models/issue_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 83001
Run options: --seed 28420

# Running:

E

/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb:10: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x000000000000f2
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin17]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
...
```

What's the right way to write my unit test?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your test as written.

I suspect you may have run into a magic column name... Rails really doesn't like it when you use `type` (or similar names) for a column - because this overloads secret, hidden variables used inside Rails itself....

Unfortunately this magic list is undocumented anywhere.

Try renaming that column something else eg "kinds" and seeing if it all starts magically working...